# "Error ... Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data.Entity.EF5, Version=6.9.9.0 ..."

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

In fact, I wanted `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6`, however, for some reason Visual Studio ADO EDMX editor wanted `MySql.Data.Entity.EF5` (same version, 6.9.9.0).

First, I checked if the NuGet packages 'MySql.Data' and 'MySql.Data.Entity' were installed.

I then issued the following command in PowerShell to reinstall all packages to help fix any .net version errors:

`update-packages -reinstall`

and proceeded to verify that all references in web.config were correct; however, the error remained. I even reinstalled [MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.6](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/), but still the same.

*(FYI: Restarting Visual Studio at each step above)*

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to simply add a new "dummy" ADO Entities Data Model to the project, referencing the same database (not sure this matters), which seemed to correct some references (somewhere) within the solution/project to the wrong version of the MySQL DLL (the error said 'EF5', but it should have been looking for 'EF6'). I'm sure there was a cache somewhere that was doing this, but just not sure where.

Edit: In retrospect, I perhaps should have tried deleting the `obj` folder first, as there are some `*AssemblyReferences*.cache` files in there. I tried rolling back to a previous version of the source (using Git) to test this, but the old version works now! So I'm sure it must have been the `obj` folder, which is ignored by Git by default.